# LotusScript space character

Tags: lotusscript

I am writing Lotusscript agent, how do I say that I need to take value in the right of space character?
For example this takes value in the right of /:

```
fld9.Value = StrRight(Cstr(doc.request(0)), "/")
```

but if I put space instead of /, it does not work. Do I need to write some kind of code there?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work with space `" "` for sure. My guess is that your expression `Cstr(doc.request(0))` does not contain a space because `Cstr()` converts e.g. numbers to string **without** a space.

If you want to get the time from a date/time value as String then better use `format()`:

```
fld9.Value = Format(doc.request(0), "hh:nn:ss")
```

Comment: Thanks Knut, I am trying to separate date from time which are in one line in such format: 06/18/2010 01:09:15. I extracted date, but can't take time value and put in separate column in my relational database.

Comment: Edited answer for date/time value

Comment: Just tried, my code:  fld3.Value = Format(doc.Created(0), "Long Time")
And comes error table with nothing written at all. For example that's how I extract DATE value: fld2.Value = doc.Created.
By the way, forgot to mention there is AM/PM in the end of time, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Thanks, tried, no error and agent works, but Time data didn't transfer to Time Column in DB2. I use Time datatype in case you wonder.

Comment: Oooh, then AM/PM is bad I guess - then use "hh:nn:ss" instead of "Long Time" - I would think that you have to convert it to time format for DB2

Comment: Actually Long Time works, and I got AM/PM transferred, I just messed up in other place haha. Thank you very much for your help Knut :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure, that the character you want to find is a space and not another whitespace character?

If it IS a space, then this would work same as in your example:

```
fld9.Value = StrRight(Cstr(doc.request(0)), " ")
```

Or to be more flexible

```
Dim strSpace as String
strSpace = Chr$(20)
fld9.Value = StrRight(Cstr(doc.request(0)), strSpace)
```

To find out, what you got there, you take a string (that you probably know) and do this:

```
Dim strSpaceChar As String
Dim lngAsc as Long
strSpaceChar = Mid$("Your String with a space", 5, 1)
' 5 = Position of the "space" character, 1 = Number characters
lngAsc = Asc( strSpaceChar )
```

If lngAsc <> 20 then you need to replace strSpace in the example above with the right Character...

If there might be different "spaces" in the text and you do not know before the run, then make an array with all known variations of "space" (the example below would consider NewLines and an HTML nbsp as Spaces)

```
Dim arrSpaces( 3 ) as String
arrSpaces( 0 ) = Chr$( 10 )
arrSpaces( 1 ) = Chr$( 13 )
arrSpaces( 2 ) = Chr$( 0 )
arrSpaces( 3 ) = Chr$( 160 )
```

and replace it with a "real" space...

```
myString = Replace( Cstr(doc.request(0)) , arrSpaces , Chr$(20) )
```

EDIT because of new kind of question: 
There are classes to handle Date / Time values. 
You could do something like:

```
Dim dtRequest as NotesDateTime
Dim strDate as String
Dim strTime as String
Set dtRequest = New NotesDateTime( doc.request(0) )
strDate = dtRequest.DateOnly
strTime = dtRequest.TimeOnly
```

Comment: Thank you very much, gonna try this!